# Title case with a list of exception words

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to come up with something that will "title" a string of words. It should capitalize all words in the string unless given words not to capitalize as an argument. But will still capitalize the first word no matter what. I know how to capitalize every word, but I dont know how to not capitalize the exceptions. Kind of lost on where to start, couldnt find much on google.

```
  def titlemaker(title, exceptions):
      return ' '.join(x[0].upper() + x[1:] for x in title.split(' '))
```

or

```
return title.title()
```

but I found that will capitalize a letter after an apostrophe so I dont think I should use it. 
Any help on how I should take into account the exceptions would be nice

example:  titlemaker('a man and his dog', 'a and') should return 'A Man and His Dog'

Comment: Possible duplicate, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728655/python-titlecase-a-string-with-exceptions

Comment: Sort of a duplicate, I saw that post, but it doesnt show anything about a function with two arguments. He also used a set list all the time, I would like to be able to write which ones I dont want to capitalize.

Comment: `def title_except(s, exceptions)` seems to have two input arguments:-)

Answer (score 4):

```
def titlemaker(title,exceptions):
    exceptions = exceptions.split(' ')
    return ' '.join(x.title() if nm==0 or not x in exceptions else x for nm,x in enumerate(title.split(' ')))

titlemaker('a man and his dog','a and') # returns "A Man and His Dog"
```

The above assumes that the input string and the list of exceptions are in the same case (as they are in your example), but would fail on something like `titlemaker('a man And his dog','a and').  If they could be in mixed case do,

```
def titlemaker(title,exceptions):
    exceptionsl = [x.lower() for x in exceptions.split(' ')]
    return ' '.join(x.title() if nm==0 or not x.lower() in exceptions else x.lower() for nm,x in enumerate(title.split(' ')))

titlemaker('a man and his dog','a and') # returns "A Man and His Dog"
titlemaker('a man AND his dog','a and') # returns "A Man and His Dog"
titlemaker('A Man And His DOG','a and') # returns "A Man and His Dog"
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try with this:**

```
def titleize(text, exceptions):
    exceptions = exceptions.split()
    text = text.split()
    # Capitalize every word that is not on "exceptions" list
    for i, word in enumerate(text):
        text[i] = word.title() if word not in exceptions or i == 0 else word
    # Capitalize first word no matter what
    return ' '.join(text)

print titleize('a man and his dog', 'a and')
```

**Output:**

```
A Man and His Dog
```

Comment: Since you already enumerate `text`, why don't you include the condition `or i == 0` in your list comprehension to eliminate the the extra `title()` in the line below it?

Comment: Done. Thank you @floydn!

Comment: Why not just call title on the final string?

Comment: @PeterWood could be. But there are a lot of ways to do it, I just picked one to answer this question. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
def titleize(text, exceptions):
    return ' '.join([word if word in exceptions else word.title()
                     for word in text.split()]).capitalize()
```

Comment: Doesn't the .title() at the end undo the exceptions? It looks like it splits the text into words, joins the words with non-exceptions title-cased, and then applies .title() to the resulting string which will title-case all words, including the exceptions.

Comment: @GarlandPope I believe you're right. I've fixed it to finally call [`capitalize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize) instead of [`title`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title) so that the first character is always a capital.

Answer (score 2):

```
import re 
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from itertools import chain

def setTitleCase(title):
    exceptions = []
    exceptions.append([word for word in stopwords.words('english')])
    exceptions.append([word for word in stopwords.words('portuguese')])
    exceptions.append([word for word in stopwords.words('spanish')])
    exceptions.append([word for word in stopwords.words('french')])
    exceptions.append([word for word in stopwords.words('german')])
    exceptions = list(chain.from_iterable(exceptions))
    list_of_words = re.split(' ', title) 
    final = [list_of_words[0].capitalize()] 
    for word in list_of_words[1:]: 
        word = word.lower()
        if word in exceptions:
            final.append(word)
        else:
            final.append(word.capitalize())
    return " ".join(final)

print(setTitleCase("a Fancy Title WITH many stop Words and other stuff"))
```

Wich gives you as answer: "A Fancy Title with Many Stop Words and other Stuff"